# For an IOS app, the view will not clear its content before drawRect as soon as initWithCoder is added to MainView.m, why?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

It is really strange that for a Single View app, I added a `MainView` class and made the `ViewController.xib` to use custom class of `MainView`, and catch the `touchesMoved` event in `ViewController.m`, and record the dot (the location).

Then in `drawRect` inside `MainView.m`, I draw the dot.  So when the program runs, all I see is a single dot on the screen, drawn to where my finger moves to...

However, as soon as I added `initWithCoder` to `MainView.m`, the behavior is totally different.  It seems like the view won't clear its content before drawing the dot, and all the dots previously drawn remain on screen, but the screen flashes a lot (I am using the new iPad with the new GPU)... seems like there are several "buffers", some with different sets of old dots, and another buffer had different set of old dots...  When my finger left the screen, it could be one of those buffers (a random buffer with different set of dots).  (one more thing: the background of the screen changed to all black.  Before, it was grey or whatever color Interface Builder set the view to).   Why does adding the `initWithCoder` as follow will create such effect?

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `initWithCoder:` method is wrong. You have to call `[super initWithCoder:aDecoder]`, not plain old `[super init]`, otherwise all the information from the xib file (including the redraw options and background colour) is lost - the `aDecoder` object contains all this information, and you are discarding it.

Comment: aha, I see... actually I wanted to achieve the effect of `clearsContextBeforeDrawing = NO`... the mistake actually caused that to happen... I wonder why if I do it in Interface Builder or in code, even when `clearsContextBeforeDrawing` is set to NO, `drawRect` always draw with a clean canvas.

Comment: You have a background colour, it will always fill with that before any drawing. Clearing the context is more about performance. You should ask a separate question explaining what you are trying to achieve.